# Maxima and minima of $x^2-x\sin x, x \in [0,\pi/2]$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

$f(x)=x^2-x\sin x, x\in [0,\pi/2]$

I reduced it to finding that $f'(x)=2x-\sin x- x\cos x>0 \space\forall x \in [0,\pi/2]$

I then simplified $f'(x)=2x-\sqrt{1+x^2}\sin({x+\arctan x})$
Now $f'(x)>2x-\sqrt{1+x^2}$ which is $>0 \forall x\in[1/\sqrt3,\pi/2]$

How to prove $f'(x)>0$for the intervel $[0,1/\sqrt3]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f'(x)=x-\sin(x)+x[1-\cos(x)]>0$ holds for all $x\in(0,\pi/2)$, the function $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\pi/2]$. This implies that it attains its minimum at $x=0$ and its maximum at $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: I asked how to prove $f'(x)>0$ for x in $[0,1/\sqrt3]$

Comment: Can you see that $x>\sin(x)$ and that $1>\cos(x)$ holds for all $x\in(0,\pi/2)$?

Comment: Oh. Got it. Thanks!